# ExpreesionEngine Plugin for Aptana

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana, expressionengine

Is there any Expressionengine code highlighter plugin for Aptana? I've read that most of Eclipse plugins are compatible with it, so theres might be an Eclipse plugin which works with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ExpressionEngine *"bundles"* for many popular Mac editors — including **Coda**, **Espresso** and **Textmate** — often referred to colloquially as the "[ExpressionEngine Developer's Toolkit](http://hellomountee.com/expressionengine-dev-toolkit)".

There's also been a lot of demand for an ExpressionEngine Language Module and Clippings Set for BBEdit as well.

However, I'm not aware of anyone who has built an ExpressionEngine code highlighter for [Aptana](http://aptana.com/).